# What airports close to the east coast of the US have attractions that are easy to get to?

Tags: airport, usa, flight-planning, flight-path

I'm currently living in Boston and fly out of KBED regularly. I'm looking into making a long cross country in a Cessna 182T to the Bahamas and am planning my route. I'm IFR rated.

I'm looking for airports generally along the east coast (east of KATL and south of KBED) that have at least one of the following and are less than a 25 minute drive from the field: diner/restaurant with at least 3 stars on yelp, museum, historic or tourist attractions.

Some places that have caught my attention:

- KBID (Block Island State, RI) - Bethany's Airport Diner is on the
  field and has 4 stars on yelp
- 0B8 (Fishers Island, NY) - friend says
  it's a 15 minute walk to a really nice golf club open to anyone
- KMYR (Myrtle Beach, SC) - there's a 100 things to do walking distance from the airport (parks, beach, restaurants, tours, etc...)
- KCHS or KJZI (Charleston, SC) - 20 minute drive to the historic downtown of the city

Really appreciate your input!

Comment: @raptortech97 I've made some edits, do you think I've removed the "opinion-based" problem?

Comment: Yeah, that looks great!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a topic of Travel.SE.

Comment: My first thought was: [Old Rhinebeck!](http://www.oldrhinebeck.org). But I guess you are looking for something completely different.

Comment: @kevin Although I think even Travel.SE generally discourages "What stuff is there to do in X place?" questions, since list-type questions generally don't fit the SE format well.

Comment: Asking for good (GA) airports to visit would be more on topic here than Travel.SE. I think reirab's point about list-type questions is more relevant, as well as the location of "east coast" being far too broad.